# C: free() invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c, sockets

I saw few topic with same question but I still can't solve my problem. So here is my code - Sockets Programming in C with XOR encryption

When server and client connected:
- User send message, eg: hello
- Server response, eg: (Server): hello (what user say)

I get that error in server's code, function handleClient(..)

Thank you
Sorry for my bad English :|

// server.c

```
/**
* Load libraries
**/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "xor.h"

/**
* Define functions
**/
void handleError(char errorMessage[]);
void handleClient(int clientSocket);
void closeSocket(int serverSocket);

/**
* Define global variables
**/
int serverSocket;

/**
* Define constants
**/
#define DEFAULT_PORT 1213
#define QUEUE_LIMIT 10
#define BUFFER_LEN 64

/**
* Main function
**/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("------------SERVER------------\n");

    int clientSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    unsigned short serverPort;
    unsigned int clientLen;

    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("Wrong argument!\n");
        exit(1);    
    }

    serverPort = atoi(argv[1]);

    if((serverSocket = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        handleError("socket() fail\n");
    }

    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_UNIX;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);

    if(bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
        handleError("bind() fail\n");
    }

    if(listen(serverSocket, QUEUE_LIMIT) < 0) {
        handleError("listen() fail\n"); 
    }

    clientLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    if((clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &clientLen)) < 0) {
        handleError("accept() fail\n");     
    } else {
        handleClient(clientSocket);
    }

    return 0;
}

/**
* Display error message
* @param char message
**/
void handleError(char errorMessage[]) 
{
    printf("ERROR: %s", errorMessage);
    closeSocket(serverSocket);
    exit(1);
}

/**
* Handle client connection
* @param int client socket
**/
void handleClient(int clientSocket)
{
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_LEN+1);
    char *key = "123456";
    char pre[BUFFER_LEN];

    while(clientSocket > 0) {
        if(recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_LEN, 0) > 0) {
            buffer = xor_decrypt(key, buffer);
            printf(">> User %d: %s", clientSocket, buffer);

            strcpy(pre, "(Server): ");
            strcat(pre, buffer);
            strcpy(buffer, pre);
            if(send(clientSocket, xor_encrypt(key, buffer), BUFFER_LEN, 0) < 0) {
                printf("send() fail\n");
                break;      
            }   
            strcpy(buffer, "");
            free(buffer);
            buffer = malloc(BUFFER_LEN+1);
        }
    }

    free(buffer);
    closeSocket(clientSocket);
}

/**
* Close socket
* @param socketid sockid that opened
*/
void closeSocket(int socket)
{
    int status = shutdown(socket, SHUT_RDWR);
    switch(status) {
        case 0:
            printf("Socket close successful!\n");
            break;
        case -1:
            printf("Can't close socket!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("shutdown() fail\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

// xor.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xor.h"

char *xor_encrypt(const char *key, char *string) 
{   
    int lenStr = strlen(string);
    int lenKey = strlen(key);

    char *encrypted = malloc(lenStr + 1);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < lenStr; i++) {
        encrypted[i] = string[i]^key[i % lenKey];
    }

    return encrypted;
}

char *xor_decrypt(const char *key, char *string) {
    return xor_encrypt(key, string);
}
```

[Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfh2g.png)

Comment: have you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: You probably forgot to terminate your receive buffer with a `'\0'` before treating it as a string.

Comment: The error message indicates that your code has written outside the bounds of the memory it was allocated and screwed up the internal accounting information used by `malloc()` et al to track what is allocated where.  If you're on a platform which [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) supports, use it to get more information about where you're going wrong.

Comment: `strcpy(pre, "(Server): ");
            strcat(pre, buffer);
            strcpy(buffer, pre);` This occurs buffer-overflow. Because `buffer` is changed by `buffer = xor_decrypt(key, buffer);`  (`char *encrypted = malloc(lenStr + 1);`)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this <3

Comment: Also If the result of the XOR operation  becomes 0, the string function can not be applied.

Answer (score 0):

In this segment of code:

```
char *xor_encrypt(const char *key, char *string) 
{   
    int lenStr = strlen(string);
    int lenKey = strlen(key);

    char *encrypted = malloc(lenStr + 1);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < lenStr; i++) {
        encrypted[i] = string[i]^key[i % lenKey];
    }
    /// at this point, new buffer is not guaranteed to be NULL terminated

    return encrypted;
}
```

It does not appear you are appending a null terminator to the end of the encrypted buffer, and because of the XOR operations, a NULL terminator is not guaranteed, or even likely.

Add this line:

```
...
for(i = 0; i < lenStr; i++) {
    encrypted[i] = string[i]^key[i % lenKey];
}
encrypted[i] = 0;//add this line to explicitly NULL terminate new buffer
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this

P/s: some one answer my question with this code but he delete his answer! @@ 
So thank you for your answer!!!

```
int lenStr = strlen(string);
int lenKey = strlen(key);
```

to

```
int lenStr = strlen(string) + 1;
int lenKey = strlen(key) + 1;
```

Comment: You are welcome, but I saw in the very next line you included `lenKey +1` in the `malloc` statement.  So I thought that you had already allocated enough space, and deleted that answer.  But glad you figured it out.

Comment: Did you see the other post about making sure the new encrypted buffer is NULL terminated?